# Read IP address of the existing GCP VM instance in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have an existing VM instance in my Google Cloud Platform project, which was created manually (not using Terraform).

Now, I want to use Terraform in order to provision a DNS record for this VM. I don't want to copy the IP address manually and hardcode it to the configuration. Is there a way for Terraform to read the public IP address of the existing VM instance and use this value as a variable when creating another resource?

Also, in general, is Terraform capable of querying data from the existing resources (not managed by Terraform)?

Comment: You have posted a good answer. Try to edit your question so that your question is not closed.

Comment: Occasionally valid topics are considered off-topic. Good questions/answers get downvoted. The world is not always fair. However, you have contributed a lot - do not stop contributing because of one situation.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform has a feature called [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html). This mechanism essentially provides a way to query the existing infrastructure and read data from the resources.

Each provider has it's own set of supported data sources. For example, GCP provider has a [google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_instance) data source.

Here's the example of how this mechanism can be used to create a DNS record for the existing VM instance:

```hcl
data "google_compute_instance" "my-instance" {
  # this is how you query/match the existing resources
  name = "unique-name-of-your-instance"
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "my-record" {
  name = "foo.example.com."
  type = "A"
  managed_zone = google_dns_managed_zone.my-zone.name
  rrdatas = [
    data.google_compute_instance.my-instance.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
  ]
}
```